# What about a "weekend replay" feature?

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I was spending some time on SO today (a Saturday) and saw some good questions with no answers, and some good answers which deserved more upvotes. But many people [doesn't access trilogy sites on weekends](http://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com), so there is a relatively small audience today.

My suggestion is: make all questions with "low" views (maybe using the same algorithm as the `Tumbleweed` badge) or unanswered status (no upvoted answers) reappear on a different day at the same time they were originally posted.  Or, at times when they are [more likely to get an answer](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/the-best-time-to-ask-a-stack-overflow-question/).

I think this can be a positive way to get more questions away from the unanswered tab.

What do you think about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The community user automatically bumps old unanswered questions periodically, so there's already a process to help the kind of questions you mention.

If the person who posted the question wants to, they can bump it, and if you are particularly interested in a question you might even bump it.

But if no one is interested in it, then the community user will bump it occasionally.

Currently the process works fairly well.

Comment: what you meant by "bump it"? to edit that question?

Answer (score 4):

Any reason you can't just go through the pages yourself? Order the questions by time (the "newest" tab and then you can easily go as far back as you want.

Why would you particularly want questions posted at 9am on Saturday to appear at 9am on Monday? It's not like the time of day at which they were posted is likely to be relevant to the question, is it?

EDIT: Any reason you can't scan down a few pages looking for questions with a low number of views?

Comment: Well, *if* you have a "replay" feature, you have to describe in some way. Taking the same time of day seems as good as anything else. Whether it's a good idea to begin with -- that's another question.

Comment: When I open SO early morning, I usually get last 5 pages to check it out. My point is to make questions with low views, unanswered, to be displayed again, without I need to look for them.

Comment: btw, I just edited my question and made a more concrete description for that feature suggestion; ty for your feedback, Jon

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jon here. When I come back after being away for a day or two, I make a special point to click on the one or two tags that I follow most closely and catch up on the recent questions. We are all in different timezones and have different schedules, so what constitutes "back in the game" to one person is going to be entirely different for another.

See also [Getting attention for unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions) -- people who post on the weekends are just going to have to be aware that they may not get as many eyes on their question as if they posted during the week. (Except for superuser -- traffic there seems to not dip as much on the weekends and during holidays as on SO and SF.)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers here are good, but I have one additional concern: volume.  The bumpings done by the Community user right now aren't too obtrusive, but this feature has the potential to do a lot more bumping than Community does.  If you get too much "replay," then questions asked right before replays will get less time on the main page/questions page, and you'll have a ripple effect of questions not getting attention.

Of course this could be artificially governed, but then the feature is less useful.